# What intent-filter to read Type 2 Tag in Nexus S (Android)?

Tags: android, tags, nfc

i have a type 2 tag, text record with type="T" and some text.

Put i try to tag this, my activity is presented in activity chooser.
I have this code in my manifest file

```
     <activity android:name=".Layout1"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
         <data android:mimeType="mime/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Why i can't caught the tag ?? i dont understand what is type="T". thanks your all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started android/NFC programming. Within my code, there're alo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" android:required="true">
</uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

for your info and hope it helps.